# How do I export the URLs saved on an iPad homescreen?

Tags: ios, bookmarks, url

Is there some way to export the URLs for all of the bookmarks added to my iPad's Home Screen (i.e. saved as icons on the home screen)?

I want to export them as HTML/XML/CSV/text, not sync them to another Apple device or just create a backup that can only be restored back to an iPad.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask, is this a once-off thing you need to do, or is it something you're wanting to do repeatedly or as part of some workflow?

Comment: what iOS and what iPad is it

Comment: IPad Air 2 with iOS 12.1

Comment: I want to export the iPad configuration as part of my regular backup routine. I transfer the data to a non-Apple system, where I want to extract the URLs. So this is not about creating a backup for safety, it is about extracting the data so that it can be used elsewhere. I would cope with some manual process, but as much automation as possible would clearly save time and effort.

Comment: Just a side question: do you own a Mac?

Comment: I use a Mac at work but do not own one myself.
This is why I want the export in an open format.

Comment: I guess that there is no hope ...

Comment: Still no way to do this it seems.